# How can i write sqlite connection code in typeorm with react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, typeorm

Here is an example but it is for postgress i want to use sqlite.

````
  type: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5432,
  username: "test",
  password: "test",
  database: "test",
  synchronize: true,
  logging: true,
  entities: [Post, Category],
  subscribers: [],
  migrations: [],
})```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
   type :"sqlite",
   database: "dbName",
   entities: [__dirname + "/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
   synchronize: true
 })
```

Comment: synchronize true will re-build the db with every build.  definately not recommended to use in production.